# How to execute ANY() SQL in Spring jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to execute the query

```
"SELECT sd.id, sd.word, sd.desc FROM word_data sd WHERE sd.word = ANY (VALUES :words)"
```

Prepare arguments

```
for(String element : key){
    listElement.add("('" + element + "')");
}

String finalString = StringUtils.join(listElement.iterator(), ",");

Map<String, Object> arg = new HashMap<>();
arg.put("words", finalString);
```

Execute queries

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, arg,
            (rs, rowNum) -> new Word(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("word"), rs.getString("desc")));
```

Exception is returned

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Syntax error (approximate position: "$1")
```

How to correctly fill in the arguments for such a query? When the arguments were inserted manually and the query was executed successfully.

Comment: You can pass the list (`key` if I understand from your question) as the parameter.

Comment: I pass in the variable `arg`